# Running Line by Line Produces Odd Result Compared to Running Lines as a Single Line with Semicolons

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a simple one line Powershell command that'll list all TCP and UDP ports of a given process name.

If I run the lines one by one, it produces the expected output. If I put all four lines of code into a single line, and separate the lines using a semicolon, it produces different results. Please see the two examples of code below:

Here are the four separate lines that set a process name, use that process name to get some PIDs based on the process name. The process PIDs are then used to filter the results from the bottom two commands.

```bsh
$processName = "outlook"
$processIds = Get-Process $processName
Get-NetTCPConnection | ? {$_.OwningProcess -in $processIds.Id}
Get-NetUDPEndpoint | ? {$_.OwningProcess -in $processIds.Id}
```

The above works. If I put all those lines into a single line and separate them with a semicolon, I get a different result:

```bsh
$processName = "outlook";$processIds = Get-Process $processName;Get-NetTCPConnection | ? {$_.OwningProcess -in $processIds.Id};Get-NetUDPEndpoint | ? {$_.OwningProcess -in $processIds.Id};
```

It is almost as if its piping the two last commands into eachother. Or maybe the formatting is off, I'm not sure. I expected the semicolons to produce the same result as if each line was being ran one by one.

Comment: Firstly, your two examples are not the same because your second example has `$processIds = Get-Process;$processName;` instead of `$processIds = Get-Process $processName;`. I can't technically explain why it is happening other than just saying "that's PowerShell's autoformatting in the console for you." You can see the same output of the last command by running `Get-NetUDPEndpoint | ? {$_.OwningProcess -in $processIds.Id} | format-list *`. Something is triggering the formatting to do a list format with all properties, which is what I can't fully explain.

Comment: Oops yeah I just fixed that in the question. That isn't the reason its failing that was just a typo in the question :P Thanks for the reply. I don't fully understand it either, it's kind've weird.

Comment: In your second example, you can expect things to be slightly different because you don't send anything to PowerShell until you hit the Enter key. So there is the difference of sending one command, processing it, and outputting it to the console vs. sending all commands, processing them all, and then waiting for one console output. The good news is that you have the ability to control how your output looks instead of relying on PowerShell to do it for you.

Comment: If you like the first output, you can replicate that with `$processName = "outlook";$processIds = Get-Process $processName;Get-NetTCPConnection | ? {$_.OwningProcess -in $processIds.Id} | ft;Get-NetUDPEndpoint | ? {$_.OwningProcess -in $processIds.Id} | ft;`. Just force PowerShell to format tabular style. All of the output data is the same with only the presentation being different.

Comment: What's the difference? I do not see any on my environment.

Comment: @montonero the effect only shows if both commands return content. Instead of using `outlook` for the process, use something that has UDP like `iexplore`, as this may show the effect.

Comment: @HAL9256 Thanks, now it's clear. This issue is only for a command prompt not for a `.ps1` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: it's by design to solve a complex issue (see Github issue #4552: [Enable formatting of different object types in same pipeline](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4552)).

What happens in the first example, is that each command outputs their object data individually. In this case, PowerShell will refer to the format file `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\NetTCPIP\Tcpip.Format.ps1xml"` to see what the default formatting for the object is. In this case, from the format file, PowerShell is told to format both objects to a table based on their type.

When you chain the commands into one, the **First** object will determine the output format for the entire line. In this example, it will be in the `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetTCPConnection` format. Since the second command outputs an object of type `.../MSFT_NetUDPEndpoint` it cannot be formatted in the same way. *Even though* it could share the same columns, since the specific object formatting is defined, PowerShell then defaults to outputting the object in fallback, best effort `Format-List *` format.

This is [by design](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4594#issuecomment-322799736) because it's hard to determine individual formatting on the fly especially when you start having arrays with mixed types. They have decided that it is therefore better to use the first object to determine type, and then handle different objects with a fallback.

We can do some testing to see the different ways that PowerShell handles formatting:

```
#For brevity sake, let's assign variables for our examples:
$processName = "outlook"
$processIds = Get-Process $processName
$TCP = Get-NetTCPConnection | ? {$_.OwningProcess -in $processIds.Id}
$UDP = Get-NetUDPEndpoint | ? {$_.OwningProcess -in $processIds.Id}
```

First individually:

```
PS> $TCP

LocalAddress                        LocalPort RemoteAddress                       RemotePort State       AppliedSetting OwningProcess
------------                        --------- -------------                       ---------- -----       -------------- -------------
0.0.0.0                             65045     0.0.0.0                             0          Bound                      24200
0.0.0.0                             56125     0.0.0.0                             0          Bound                      24200

PS> $UDP

LocalAddress                             LocalPort
------------                             ---------
::                                       5353
0.0.0.0                                  5353
```

This is exactly what we want. However, when we chain our objects the output will be:

```
PS> $TCP; $UDP

LocalAddress                        LocalPort RemoteAddress                       RemotePort State       AppliedSetting OwningProcess
------------                        --------- -------------                       ---------- -----       -------------- -------------
0.0.0.0                             65045     0.0.0.0                             0          Bound                      24200
0.0.0.0                             56125     0.0.0.0                             0          Bound                      24200

Caption                  :
Description              :
ElementName              :
InstanceID               : ::++5353
CommunicationStatus      :
DetailedStatus           :
HealthState              :
InstallDate              :
Name                     :
OperatingStatus          :
OperationalStatus        :
PrimaryStatus            :
Status                   :
StatusDescriptions       :
AvailableRequestedStates :
EnabledDefault           : 2
EnabledState             :
OtherEnabledState        :
RequestedState           : 5
TimeOfLastStateChange    :
TransitioningToState     : 12
AggregationBehavior      :
Directionality           :
CreationTime             : 2019-04-15 9:05:09 AM
LocalAddress             : ::
LocalPort                : 5353
OwningProcess            : 24200
PSComputerName           :

Caption                  :
Description              :
ElementName              :
InstanceID               : 0.0.0.0++5353
CommunicationStatus      :
DetailedStatus           :
HealthState              :
InstallDate              :
Name                     :
OperatingStatus          :
OperationalStatus        :
PrimaryStatus            :
Status                   :
StatusDescriptions       :
AvailableRequestedStates :
EnabledDefault           : 2
EnabledState             :
OtherEnabledState        :
RequestedState           : 5
TimeOfLastStateChange    :
TransitioningToState     : 12
AggregationBehavior      :
Directionality           :
CreationTime             : 2019-04-15 9:05:09 AM
LocalAddress             : 0.0.0.0
LocalPort                : 5353
OwningProcess            : 24200
PSComputerName           :
```

The first object displays properly, and the second falls back to a `Format-List *`. Now, let's add in a `Select` statement:

```
PS> $TCP | Select LocalAddress, LocalPort ; $UDP

LocalAddress LocalPort
------------ ---------
0.0.0.0          65045
0.0.0.0          56125
::                5353
0.0.0.0           5353
```

Here we see that since we are transforming the TCP object into a `PSCustomObject`, with the `Select` statement, our `$UDP` object can "fit" into the table format, *it flows in with the rest of the objects in the pipeline!* (Note: this could be unexpected, as you don't know where one object ends and the next begins!)

The final workaround is to essentially "flush" the pipeline by using `Out-String`:

```
PS> $TCP | Out-String; $UDP

LocalAddress                        LocalPort RemoteAddress                       RemotePort State       AppliedSetting OwningProcess
------------                        --------- -------------                       ---------- -----       -------------- -------------
0.0.0.0                             65045     0.0.0.0                             0          Bound                      24200
0.0.0.0                             56125     0.0.0.0                             0          Bound                      24200


LocalAddress                             LocalPort
------------                             ---------
::                                       5353
0.0.0.0                                  5353
```

This gives us the output we likely would like to see, but it's probably still not best practice to chain multiple object types in the same line.