# Measure -Sum -Property does not produce output

Tags: powershell

```
$Data = @()
foreach($i in 1..10) {
    $Data += New-Object PSObject -Property @{        
        Money = 10
    }
}

echo "-----Data-----"
$Data

echo "-----Measure-----"
$Data | Measure -Sum -Property "Money"
```

Outputs:

```
-----Data-----

Money
-----
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
-----Measure-----
```

If you run this code, you see that line `$Data | Measure -Sum -Property "Money"` does not generate any output. BUT! if you comment out line `$Data`, you get

```
-----Data-----
-----Measure-----


Count    : 10
Average  : 
Sum      : 100
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : Money
```

as expected.
Why???? Why do same statements return different results ???

Comment: I get the same measure results from a 5.1 console in either scenario.

Comment: You can force output piping to `|Out-String`. BTW if you reverse the order and put the Measure first you see that the mechanism to delay output and have only one header doesn't work correct always.

Comment: *Why do same statements return different results ???* Them return the same result, but then it get formatted differently, because formatter pickup format from earlier object in pipeline.

Comment: @PetSerAl is right. Try `New-Object PSObject -Property @{Money = 10; Sum = ''}` while defining the `$Data` object.

Answer (score 2):

As a note, this only happens when you run the entire code snippit as a single statement (i.e. as a script from the ISE, or copying an pasting the entire code snippit). If, instead, you run each statement line individually from the PowerShell console, you will get the expected results.

As @PetSerAl says, the issue is related to formatting See my answer here for more details: [Running Line by Line Produces Odd Result Compared to Running Lines as a Single Line with Semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55854591/2150063)

Running:

```
PS C:\> $Data = @()
>> foreach($i in 1..10) {
>>     $Data += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
>>         Money = 10
>>     }
>> }
>>
>> echo "-----Data-----"
>> $Data
>>
>> echo "-----Measure-----"
>> $Data | Measure -Sum -Property "Money"
```

Outputs:

```
-----Data-----

Money
-----
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
-----Measure-----
```

When you chain the commands into one, the **First** object will determine the output format for the entire line. So looking at the types we get:

```
PS C:\> $Data.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS C:\> ($Data | Measure -Sum -Property "Money").GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    GenericMeasureInfo                       Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureInfo
```

In this example, the first object `$Data` is of type `Object[]`, and so it will try to format everything else in the `Object[]` format. Since the second command outputs an object of type `GenericMeasureInfo` it cannot be formatted in the same way. Since the two formats are incompatible, the Measure object information is dropped and not outputted.

When you comment out the first `$Data` statement, then the Measure object is the only thing outputted, and yes, you see a properly formatted Measure object.

Now, let's flip it around:

```
PS C:\Temp> $Data = @()
>> foreach($i in 1..10) {
>>     $Data += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
>>         Money = 10
>>     }
>> }
>> echo "-----Measure-----"
>> $Data | Measure -Sum -Property "Money"
>>
>> echo "-----Data-----"
>> $Data
```

Outputs:

```
-----Measure-----


Count    : 10
Average  :
Sum      : 100
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : Money

-----Data-----
Money : 10

Money : 10

Money : 10

Money : 10

Money : 10

Money : 10

Money : 10

Money : 10

Money : 10

Money : 10
```

Well that may seem weird, because the `$Data` object *did* output this time, but it didn't output in a table format. Instead, it followed different formatting rules. The first object is of type `GenericMeasureInfo`, and so it will try to format everything else in the `GenericMeasureInfo` format. Since the second command outputs an object of type `Object[]`, it cannot be formatted in the same way. But in this case, instead of dropping the information, PowerShell figures out that it can fall back to outputting `$Data` formatted as a List (hence you see `"Money : 10"`).

`Out-String` is the other way of doing things:

```
PS C:\> $Data = @()
>> foreach($i in 1..10) {
>>     $Data += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
>>         Money = 10
>>     }
>> }
>>
>> echo "-----Data-----"
>> $Data | Out-String
>>
>> echo "-----Measure-----"
>> $Data | Measure -Sum -Property "Money"
-----Data-----

Money
-----
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10
   10



-----Measure-----


Count    : 10
Average  :
Sum      : 100
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : Money
```

`Out-String` works in this case because it converts the output object type format from `Object[]` to a `String` format, which the Measure object knows how output to.

Answer (score 0):

As @LotPings said, with Out-String code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common gotcha.  Format-table is implicitly running, and it doesn't know how to display different sets of columns.  Piping the script through format-list works ok.  Another weird workaround is to put get-date at the beginning of the script.  For some reason, a known object type (that has a format file) at the top makes the output "better".  You can also use format-table and format-date for individual commands.