# Why is verbose redirection creating a line between data in exported CSV file?

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have the following code that imports two csv files and merges them together. As part of the merge I remove the two files used and export one main CSV file.

```
$csvfiles | ForEach-Object {
    Import-Csv "$csvLocation\$_";
    Remove-Item "$csvLocation\$_" -Verbose 4>&1 | tee .\log.txt -Append
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "$csvLocation\$DBName.csv" -Force
```

The CSV generated looks like this with the `4>&1` verbose redirection:

[image: extra line]

Notice the extra empty in between row between server1 and server2.

The CSV I'm expecting should be like this (no in between extra row):

```
server  Database    role    members
server1 DB1 role1   memberx
server1 DB1 role2   membery
server2 DB1 role1   memberx
server2 DB1 role2   membery
```

Of course without this part

```
4>&1|tee .\log.txt -append
```

the exported CSV looks good. However, I want the verbose messages printed to the console and file (with `4>&1 | tee .\log.txt -Append` it only seems to print to file unfortunately).

> VERBOSE: Performing remove...

and the only way it works is with `4>&1`.

I tried redirecting to a variable. I tried many things but to no avail.

---

**UPDATE**: In regards to the second solution HAL offered below.

```
$csvfiles | ForEach-Object {
    Import-Csv "$csvLocation\$_" | Export-Csv -Append -NoTypeInformation "$csvLocation\$DBName.csv" -Force;
    Remove-Item "$csvLocation\$_" -Verbose 4>&1 | tee .\log.txt -Append
}
```

the output i'd normally see on the console with just `-verbose` looked like this:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target
"D:\MyFiles\Scripts\Migration\CSVFiles\Database1_RolesMembers_server1.domain.com.c
sv".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target
"D:\MyFiles\Scripts\Migration\CSVFiles\Database1_RolesMembers_server2.domain.com.c
sv".
```

however, HAL's code results in this verbose console output:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target
"D:\MyFiles\Scripts\Migration\CSVFiles\Datab
VERBOSE: ase1_RolesMembers_server1.domain.com.csv".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target
"D:\MyFiles\Scripts\Migration\CSVFiles\Datab
VERBOSE: ase1_RolesMembers_server2.domain.com.csv".
```

of course its insignificant but its worth noting the strange output style anyways

as far as the csv file generated, it STILL results in empty line, but even more:

[image: csv]

Comment: Well, you merge verbose records into the standard stream, none of which have `server`, `Database`, `role` or `members` properties, so each will result in an empty row

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen wouldnt that then result in 4 lines?

Comment: I'm assuming you have 2 csv files, so one empty row after each set of actual csv rows (you probably won't notice the second/last one in Excel)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen oh i see, you meant "so each will result in an empty row" as in each csv file not each property, right?

Comment: I meant "each verbose message record", sorry for the confusing wording. Posted an answer

Comment: @HAL9256 can you take a look at this please?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician can you take a look at this thread please?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen posted some comments on the answer. can you take a look at them? thanks!

Comment: Change your `tee` to `add-content`, and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician nope, add-content doesnt work either. however, HAL's solution worked finally :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is all about objects, streams and trying to force two different objects into the same stream. What is happening is illustrated with my SO answer here: [Running Line by Line Produces Odd Result Compared to Running Lines as a Single Line with Semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55854591/2150063)

TLDR: Basically what is happening is you are trying to pass 2 different objects down the same pipeline (see [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6v)), and PowerShell does a "best effort" interpretation which is a "bleahh -> blank" interpretation when it gets to `Export-CSV`. It also explains why no output to the console is displayed.

The best way to interpret what is going down the pipe is to break it up and assign to variables to see what is going on:

Unrolling the loop, the First command, and type is:

```
PS C:\> $csv = Import-Csv a.csv
PS C:\> $csv.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Second command is:

```
PS C:\> $ri = Remove-Item a.csv -Verbose 4>&1 | tee .\log.txt -Append
PS C:\> $ri.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    VerboseRecord                            System.Management.Automation.InformationalRecord
```

Basically what is happening is, The first command:

```
Import-CSV ...
```

Output an `Object[]` array to the Information (1) stream.

The second command:

```
Remove-Item -Verbose
```

Outputs to the Verbose (4) stream.

The third command, the redirect:
    4>&1 ...

Outputs the Verbose (4) stream content to the Information (1) stream.

The fourth command,

```
... | tee .\log.txt -Append
```

Takes the `Remove-Item` redirected output on the Information (1) stream, and outputs to *both* the Information (1) stream *and* the log file.

When we combine them inside the ForEach-Object loop, we are creating an array of competing objects on **the Information (1) stream**:

```
PS C:\> 1..2|foreach{$csv; $ri}

server  Database role  members
------  -------- ----  -------
server1 DB1      role1 memberx
server1 DB1      role2 membery
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\a.csv".
server1 DB1      role1 memberx
server1 DB1      role2 membery
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\a.csv".
```

These competing objects then get passed down the pipeline to the next `Export-Csv` command:

```
 1..2 | foreach{$csv,$ri} | Export-Csv .\out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This gets us a "Raw" CSV:

```
"server","Database","role","members"
"server1","DB1","role1","memberx"
"server1","DB1","role2","membery"
,,,
"server1","DB1","role1","memberx"
"server1","DB1","role2","membery"
,,,
```

Where we can clearly see the 4 objects were being passed down the pipeline. The `Export-Csv` gets 4 objects:

1. `Object[]` array
2. `VerboseRecord` object (the `Remove-Item -Verbose` redirected output)
3. The second `Object[]` array
4. The second `VerboseRecord` object

This is where PowerShell will take the first `Object[]` array object to build the structure of the `Export-Csv` file. It will then take the `VerboseRecord` object, and since it doesn't have a way to "fit" it into the CSV, it outputs an empty record. It then  takes the second `Object[]`, and since it "fits", will output it to the CSV. It will then take the second `VerboseRecord` object, and, again, since it doesn't have a way to "fit" it into the CSV, it outputs an empty record.

Notice that all 4 objects are in the CSV, even if PowerShell didn't know what to do with them. This is why you see no output on the PowerShell console. The Information (1) stream content is fully being directed down the pipeline to be consumed by the `Export-Csv` cmdlet, and **not** the console Host. *This* is why you don't "see" the `-Verbose` output from the `Remove-Item` command on the console, but you do see it in the file.

TLDR2: Lesson 1: Don't output multiple things to the pipeline if you have something that consumes it in the end. With pipelines, only try to work with one thing at a time.

The code can be fixed 2 ways: If you need pipelines, split the two operations into ... well... two operations to prevent corruption of the pipeline:

```
$csvfiles | ForEach-Object {
    Import-Csv "$csvLocation\$_";
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "$csvLocation\$DBName.csv" -Force

$csvfiles | ForEach-Object {
    Remove-Item "$csvLocation\$_" -Verbose 4>&1 | tee .\log.txt -Append
}
```

Or, IMHO, don't ForEach into a pipeline and expect everything to work, as things may have to be accumulated into memory before being passed on. Eliminate the end pipeline consumer and pull the `Export-Csv` into the `ForEach-Object` loop, and append your content into it.

Edit: Don't forget to start off with an empty CSV File first :-)

```
Remove-Item "$csvLocation\$DBName.csv" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$csvfiles | ForEach-Object {
    Import-Csv "$csvLocation\$_" | Export-Csv -Append -NoTypeInformation "$csvLocation\$DBName.csv" -Force;
    Remove-Item "$csvLocation\$_" -Verbose 4>&1 | tee .\log.txt -Append
}
```

Comment: very nice breakdown, thanks HAL! i used your second solution and check out my UPDATE in my post. its kinda fixed the issue but at the same time its resulted in other issues. the csv file now thats exported STILL contains empty lines, but even more interesting is after the second empty row, it prints back the same data with no empty rows all in the same file.

Comment: Have you removed the old CSV file? i.e. using `-Append` means you have to remove the csv file first (I have updated the post)

Comment: the 1st way solution worked (2 foreach'es). how come the second one requires  removing the csv file first while the first way doesnt?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you merge verbose records into the standard stream, none of which have server, Database, role or members properties, so each verbose message will result in an empty row after the records of each csv file.

Move the merge redirector to the outer pipeline instead - at that point `Export-Csv` will have written everything in the standard output stream to file, and you'll have only the verbose messages left:

```
$csvfiles | ForEach-Object {
    Import-Csv "$csvLocation\$_"
    Remove-Item "$csvLocation\$_" -Verbose 
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "$csvLocation\$DBName.csv" -Force 4>&1 |tee .\log.txt -Append
```

Comment: its not printing to the file :( its as if this part is ignored 4>&1 |tee .\log.txt -Append

Comment: i did think of redirecting the verbose after the export btw, not directly after force but on another line because i assume 4 holds all verbose output anyways. it didnt work. i am thinking the same is happening here. it seems like the only wya it'll actually capture the verbose is piping it directly after the -verbose and not outside it